# как получить ссылку из стим маркета?

Tags: python, selenium

мне нужна ссылка типа `//rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198084749846A698323590D7935523998312483177`

я нашел похожий вопрос на стак оферфлоу [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63722523/get-inspect-link-from-item-on-steam-community-market)

но код который там есть не работает выходит ошибка AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_class_name'

если кто-то сталкивался помогите плз)

p.s эта ссылка появляется когда нажимаешь на стрелку под картинкой (осмотреть оружие)

Comment: теперь этот код пишется вот так ```driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "class_name")``` и нужно перед этим сделать импорт ```from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если актуализировать код из ответа по привидённой вами ссылке, то получится:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
baseurl = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29"
driver.get(baseurl)
btns = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "market_actionmenu_button")
for btn in btns:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
    popup = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#market_action_popup_itemactions > a")
    href = popup.get_attribute('href')
    print(href)
```

Вывод:

```
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M3853416968866993694A27381464292D7657883414362097115
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M3853416968865797474A27384751481D7927639961663753561
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M3868053667660495905A27386567114D183141840705595189
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M3863550068030095113A27385733957D4757596057234588657
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M3860172368312591687A27385631676D2353707792929680861
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M3863550068024990833A27379791610D14611938666659753457
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M3857920568497694523A27386430279D14899715761024945589
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M3857920568497701763A27386397164D903080079262493009
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M3857920568497703043A27386386827D596202384362440691
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M3857920568497700143A27386411353D722527353036795735
```